# Changing service user - What are the impacts?

Tags: sql-server

We just moved to Google Cloud our Microsoft SQL Server infrastructure, in which we have some stored procedures that call the xp_cmdshell (I know that isn't recommended) for retrieving information about the file system. The problem is that in the old infrastructure we had as Service account for SQL a Domain account which we can share some folders. But in this installation we have as Service account `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` and we cannot share with him the folders we need to share.

The question are

1. There are some impacts by changing the Service account?
2. There is a way to roll back to the old account (`NT Service\MSSQLSERVER`) without knowing the password?

I tried looking for answer but without any luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i dont' know, but i think you can create a proxy user for xp_cmdshell, would that solve your issue?

Comment: I already tried, but seems that doesn't work as expected and still have the "Access is denied" when i try to run the "dir" command

Comment: what does `exec sys.xp_cmdshell  'echo %USERNAME%'`outputs? did you actually give user the rights?

Comment: "echo %USERNAME%" give me "MSSQLSERVER". The problem is that I can't give this user the permissions on the folder I have to share, 'cause is a local account and can't see him on the domain share.

Comment: That means you didn't setup proxy account? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xp-cmdshell-proxy-account-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The creation of a proxy account Requires CONTROL SERVER permission that I don't have with NT Service\MSSQLSERVER